# Adding Embedded Code Block Tag, for ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-disambiguation

I don't have the minimal reputation to add a tag, so I would like to request `embedded-code-block` be added as a tag (after discussion and review).

Other **current** considerations include:

- `embedded-code`  **exists**

  - needs description revised;

    - improperly instructs usage to out-of-context `embedded`
    - undeterminable whether this was to refer to the in-line code of the code block.
- `code-block` **doesn't exist**

  - seems synonymous/interchangable to **Embedded Code Block**
  - reference: **[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0111sbh(v=vs.100).aspx)**

---

### [Embedded Code Block - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135(v=vs.140).aspx)

> An embedded code block is server code that executes during the page's render phase. The code in the block can execute programming statements and call functions in the current page class.

*Mention Worthy:*

> Embedded code blocks are supported in ASP.NET Web Forms pages primarily to preserve backward compatibility with older ASP technology.

---

### This was prompted by...

`asp.net` question improperly using `inline` - presumably - in lieu of `in-line code` (which makes for a difficult tagging).

### [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451702/how-to-properly-use-asp-net-server-tags)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think we need special tag for "code that is on aspx/cshtml/php/whatever page" as in most cases just fact of using web framework tag implies some sort of code/markup mix when rendering pages. Additionally in most cases people just have no idea how such code can be named and tagging will not help to find such questions anyway.

I think "C# + asp.Net" (or VB.Net + asp.Net) + sample of aspx are enough to make it clear what question is about for your particular case.

"embedded-code" seem to already cover it as you've pointed out, but there aren't really many questions marked with this tag.

If provided sample requires tags to pinpoint part that causes the problem there is a good chance question deserve good edit or close as lacking clear sample.

Comment: I agree; however, apart from language and/or platform specific (which is pertinent to the Question and susequent answers), I regard the tags to be community serving. There are individuals in SO who routinely contribute by modifying questions, tags, and headlines/titles without the intention of providing an answer or addressing the OP. This is their expertise.  I'm not particularly concerned with regards to the usefulness to users that are looking for an existing Q&A that pertains to them (though; it is leagues more pertinet then `C#` and `ASP.Net` are to those that might be searching).

Comment: "I'm not particularly concerned with regards to the usefulness to users that are looking for an existing Q&A that pertains to them " using tags for refining their search I mean..